# Force execute taskReport on build failures?

Tags: gradle

Gradle 1.4 has new test report aggregate task:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/release-notes#stand-alone-test-report-task

```
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/all-tests")
    reportOn subprojects*.test
}
```

Is there a way to make this task run even when build fails? Currently if I do:

```
taskReport.dependsOn test
build.dependsOn taskReport
```

it executes only if build is success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news first: Upcoming enhancements to Gradle's task model, currently scheduled for Gradle 1.6, will address this and similar use cases.

Meanwhile, the possibilities are limited. One option is to run with `--continue`, although this will continue with other tasks as well. Another potential option is to register a [`org.gradle.api.execution.TaskExecutionListener`](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionListener.html) (via `gradle.project.addListener()`) and have it call `testReport.generateReport()` after a `Test` task has failed. Although calling a task directly is heavily discouraged (and often won't produce the expected behavior), it might do as a temporary workaround in this particular case.